# Alternative for Web Language Model API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I want to use probabilities from Microsoft N-gram language model for my research. Previously, we could access this language model using Web Language Model API but this service was discontinued a couple of months ago. Is anyone aware of any other Microsoft service which gives the same information? I already checked out the "Azure ML studio" links mentioned on the web page but could not find any information about Language model API.

Answer (score 0):

There is another similar service on azure which is Bing Spell Check API.